# How to upload multiple documents to SharePoint at the same time?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am trying to upload many documents to a library of SharePoint 2007, but it's too bad that I have to upload each by itself. Isn't there a way to upload more than one at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the multiple upload control, its an activex so you will have to use IE

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/working-with-sharepoint-document-libraries-HA001141287.aspx

> - Click Upload Document.
> - On the Upload Document page, click Upload Multiple Files.
> - Go the folder where you downloaded the practice files.
> - Select the two Word files (Memo_Draft.doc and Memo_Final.doc) by
>     selecting the check box next to each
>     file.
> - Click Save and Close.

If you cannot see the option, you may need to update to the latest CU

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/17b654fd-6e83-47b6-80ab-995ed1eabae9